# How does Nathan Brazil know Wu Julee?

Tags: midnight-at-the-well-of-souls

Apologies if this is a little vague, but I don't have my copy of the book to hand, so I'm going by my fallible memory.

In Midnight At The Well Of Souls, we're introduced to the starship captain Nathan Brazil, who's transporting a collection of passengers to another planet. One of the passengers is Wu Julee, who is secretly

> a drug addict, being used as the "stick" part of the drug-traffickers threats.

Nathan Brazil has a strong feeling that he knows Wu Julee from somewhere, and that is one of the reasons that he takes the actions that he does later in the book; but I can't for the life of me figure out *where* that comes from.

I don't recall it being mentioned at any point later in the book, and I'm unaware of whether it's covered in other of Jack Chalker's works, so it just seems like it's a gap in the plot.

Am I missing something? Did I somehow make this up? Or is there a mention of how Nathan Brazil actually knows her?

Comment: I don't think you're making it up, I remember this as well (but it's been decades since I read the books).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The memory isn't knowing Wu Julee personally, but thinking about her name and her possible ethnic origin:

> Wu Julee, the manifest said her name was. *Julie Wu?* mused a corner of his brain. There is was again! Damn! He tried to grab onto the source of the thought, but it vanished.
>
> *But she does look Chinese*, said that little corner, and then the thought retreated again.
>
> *Chinese*. That word meant something once. He knew it did. Where did those terms come from? And why couldn't he remember where they came from? Hell, almost everybody had those characteristics these days, he thought.
>
> Then, suddenly, the thought was out of his mind, as such thoughts always were, and he was back on his main track.

At the start of the story, Brazil isn't consciously aware of who and what he really is, and thus how old he really is. So the random thoughts about what the ancient version of her name would be and where her appearance would suggest she came from, which is long forgotten by that time, seem to come out of nowhere and he doesn't know where they come from or understand why he's thinking them. It's not about her personally except insofar as it's triggering ancient memories of his own, as obviously has happened to him in the past.

His subsequent actions are based on her situation as a sex-slave and sponge addict, and then feeling responsibility to try and save her, which then gets carried to the Well and their subsequent adventures.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the quote - that does make it a little clearer. I wonder if my memory mixed her up with the diplomat; I remember him explicitly saying he'd met the original.

Comment: Ah yes, Serge Ortega (the walrus-snake) had been a fellow starship pilot and they had known each other before Ortega stumbled into a Gate.